# Are the plus and minus buttons in Android calendar standard buttons?

Tags: android, user-interface, button

The Android calendar app shows round "+" and "-" buttons for adding or removing notifications (in the view for editing/creating events). Are those buttons standard or custom buttons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are custom buttons. However, since [the Calendar application is open source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/), you can see how they do it. The button background, like any button, is a `StateListDrawable`.